# push is working only if the branch is already created in remote repository (libgit2)

Tags: c++, libgit2

I performed "git push" equivalent in libgit2...when I try it on some branch, that is actually created also in remote repository, it works good. But if I have some branch, which is created just locally, push is not performed.

When I perform "git push origin test_branch" in cmd, this is printed

- [new branch]      test_branch -> test_branch

I want my program to create this branch in remote repository, like git does.

Some ideas how to do that?

```
    string path="path/to/repo";
    int result=0;

    git_libgit2_init();
    const char * REPO_PATH = path.c_str();
    git_repository * repo = nullptr;
    git_repository_open(&repo, REPO_PATH);
    git_remote_callbacks callbacks = GIT_REMOTE_CALLBACKS_INIT;

    // get the remote.
    git_remote* remote = NULL;
    git_remote_lookup(&remote, repo, "origin");

    // connect to remote
    callbacks.credentials = cred_acquire_cb;
    git_remote_connect(remote, GIT_DIRECTION_PUSH,&callbacks,NULL,NULL);
    if (1 != git_remote_connected(remote)) cerr << "problem connecting to remote" << endl;

    // add a push refspec
    if (0 != git_remote_add_push(repo,"origin", "refs/heads/test_branch:refs/heads/test_branch")) cerr << "git_remote_add_push() returned error value!" << endl;

    // configure options
    git_push_options options;
    if (0!=git_push_init_options(&options, GIT_PUSH_OPTIONS_VERSION)) cerr << "git_push_init_options() returned error value!" << endl;

    // do the push
    result=git_remote_upload(remote, NULL, &options);

    if (result != 0) cerr << "git_remote_upload() failed" << endl;

    git_remote_disconnect(remote);
    git_remote_free(remote);
    git_repository_free(repo);
    git_libgit2_shutdown();
```